# ar-drone Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined intermittent data

Tags: node.js, gps, ar.drone

When I use this code I see error messages, then gps data then back to error messages. Can anyone tell me why this happens?

```
var arDrone = require('ar-drone');
var droneClient = arDrone.createClient();
droneClient.config('general:navdata_demo', 'FALSE'); // get back all data the copter can send
droneClient.config('general:navdata_options', 777060865); // turn on GPS

droneClient.on('navdata', function(navdata) {

  try {
    console.log(navdata.gps.latitude + ', ' + navdata.gps.longitude);
}
catch(err) {
    console.log(err.message);
}


});
```

Here is what I see when I execute this. 
It seems the gps data never comes back.

Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined 43.6330829, -116.4467156 43.6330829, -116.4467156 43.6330829, -116.4467156 43.6330829, -116.4467156 43.6330829, -116.4467156 43.6330829, -116.4467156 43.6330829, -116.4467156 43.6330829, -116.4467156 43.6330829, -116.4467156 43.6330829, -116.4467156 43.6330829, -116.4467156 43.6330829, -116.4467156 43.6330829, -116.4467156 43.6330829, -116.4467156 43.6330829, -116.4467156 43.6330829, -116.4467156 43.6330829, -116.4467156 43.6330829, -116.4467156 43.6330829, -116.4467156 43.6330829, -116.4467156 Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined

Comment: When you let this program run for a long time (a minute or two), the GPS data never comes back?  Is your drone indoors or outdoors?  What's the drone's firmware version (you can check in the Freeflight app)?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the navdata event has no `gps` property.  Try logging `navdata` instead of `navdata.gps.latitude` and `navdata.gps.longitude`.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is I'm not interested in just logging. I want to get to a point where I can send it on missions. For that I need to be able to sett a latitude variable and a longitude variable. I only want those 2 pieces of data not the whole kitchen sink.